# How to loop over a number in React inside JSX

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need to be able to loop over a number and return some jsx. For example

```
<ul>
 {for(i =0; i < 10; i++){
   return <li>{i}</li>
 }}
</ul>
```

This is not exactly what I want to do, but if I can solve this then I should be able to complete what I need to do. This however returns expression expected on the `for`. I have done some research and people say you can't use `for` loops inside of jsx because they do not return anything.

How do I go about looping over a number to return some amount of jsx?

Answer (score 103, accepted):

You could use `Array.from()` instead.

```js
let App = () => {
  return <ul>{Array.from(Array(10), (e, i) => {
    return <li key={i}>{i}</li>
  })}</ul>
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('app')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16.1.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16.1.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

You can also use ES6 spread syntax with `map()` method.

```js
let App = () => {
  return <ul>{[...Array(10)].map((e, i) => {
    return <li key={i}>{i}</li>
  })}</ul>
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('app')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16.1.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16.1.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Answer (score 13):

You can do it like this :

```
createElements(n){
    var elements = [];
    for(i =0; i < n; i++){
        elements.push(<li>{i}</li>);
    }
    return elements;
}

<ul>
    {this.createElements(20)}
</ul>
```

Comment: This is the way I would do it too. JSX is helpful for somethings, but limiting for others, and where you find it limiting, it mades sense to just write a block of normal JS code, and then call that function in you JSX. This has the added advantage of keeping your JSX more concise and human readable.

Answer (score 5):

You need to use recursive iterators such as map, forEach, filter etc. If you really need to do something like this you can

```
const statelessComp = props => {
    let arr = Array.apply(null, {length: 10}).map(Number.call, Number);
    return (    
        <ul>
            {arr.map(item => {
                return <li>{item}</li> 
            })}
        </ul>
    )
}
```

edit: [these are the functions you should familiarize yourself with](https://medium.com/@JeffLombardJr/understanding-foreach-map-filter-and-find-in-javascript-f91da93b9f2c)

Comment: Thank you , I just have to loop over a number unfortunately so I couldn't find a way to use map, but this way lets me do that.

Answer (score 5):

This is the simple way

```
createElements(number){
    var elements = [];
    for(i =0; i < number; i++){
        elements.push(<div className="list-item">{i} - Some text or element</div>);
    }
    return elements;
}
```

In return statement

```
<div>
    {this.createElements(10)}
</div>
```

Comment: This is the most logical/elegant solution I saw.. At least I'm taking a number and through a function I'm returning jsx instead of creating an array to map through it as most answers say!

Answer (score 1):

you can use

```
<ul>
   <li>{[...Array.from(Array(10).keys())].map((num, i) => <p key={i}>{num}</p>)}</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me
https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/javascript/react+loop+number+of+times

```
const n = 8;

{[...Array(n)].map((elementInArray, index) => ( 
    <div className="" key={index}> Whatever needs to be rendered repeatedly... </div> 
    ) 
)}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind adding a very common and useful library, you can use lodash and map in this situation and it will be nice and clean.

```
import _ from "lodash";

return (
    <ul>{_.range(1, 10).map(i => (<li>i</li>))}<ul>
)
```

Answer (score 0):

this is one way to do it by using

> Array.from()

method which takes in two arguments. the first is the length, and the second is a callback function to do what ever you want on the looped numbers. here is an example which logs out numbers from 0 to 9

```
const sampleArray = Array.from({length:10},(_,index)=>{console.log(index)})
```